# Fetch Core Data in Widget when app is in background

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, cloudkit, widgetkit

I have an app and a widget that share Core Data + CloudKit with an app group.

When I make a change in app, widget refresh instantly on same device.

But when i make a change in app on a second device, widget never refresh on the first device until i reopen the app on this device. How can I achieve this ?

I tried to fetch in foreground and background and both in app and directly in widget.

Thanks for your help.

Here is my Core Data Stack :

```
@propertyWrapper
class Container {
    
    @objc static func Creload(_ notification: Notification) {
        let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "mygroup")
        container.performBackgroundTask { context in
            context.perform {
                let request = Transaction.request
                let results = try! context.fetch(request)
                let balance = results.filter { !$0.isPending }.map(\.amount).reduce(0, +)
                defaults?.set(balance, forKey: "Bbalance")
            }
        }
        try! container.viewContext.setQueryGenerationFrom(.current)
        let results = try! container.viewContext.fetch(Transaction.request)
        let balance = results.filter { !$0.isPending }.map(\.amount).reduce(0, +)
        defaults?.set(balance, forKey: "Fbalance")
        defaults?.synchronize()
        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
    }
    
    @objc static func Sreload(_ notification: Notification) {
        let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "mygroup")
        container.performBackgroundTask { context in
            context.perform {
                let request = Transaction.request
                let results = try! context.fetch(request)
                let balance = results.filter { !$0.isPending }.map(\.amount).reduce(0, +)
                defaults?.set(balance, forKey: "Bbalance")
            }
        }
        let results = try! container.viewContext.fetch(Transaction.request)
        let balance = results.filter { !$0.isPending }.map(\.amount).reduce(0, +)
        defaults?.set(balance, forKey: "Fbalance")
        defaults?.synchronize()
        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
    }
    
    private static let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "myapp")
    
    var wrappedValue: NSManagedObjectContext {
        Self.container.viewContext
    }
    
    var container: NSPersistentContainer {
        Self.container
    }
    
    init(_ observed: Bool = false) {
        let id = "mygroup"
        let name = "myapp"
        let container = Self.container
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = FileManager.default.containerURL(
            forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: id)!
            .appendingPathComponent("\(name).sqlite")
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, _ in }
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        
        if observed {
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                Self.self,
                selector: #selector(Self.Creload(_:)),
                name: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange,
                object: container.viewContext)
            
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                Self.self,
                selector: #selector(Self.Sreload(_:)),
                name: .NSPersistentStoreRemoteChange,
                object: container.persistentStoreCoordinator)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Widget :

```
@main
struct BalanceWidget: Widget {
    private var container = Container(true).container

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: "Balance", provider: Provider(moc: container)) {
            EntryView(entry: $0, context: container)
            }
            .configurationDisplayName("Balance")
            .description("Current and available balances")
            .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall])
            
    }
}

struct EntryView : View {
    var entry: Entry
    let Fbalance: Double
    let Bbalance: Double
    let VFbalance: Double
    let VBbalance: Double

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("WidgetBackground")
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    VStack {
                        Text(Fbalance.currency)
                            .bold().font(.system(.title3, design: .rounded))
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                        Text(Bbalance.currency)//entry.availableString)
                            .bold().font(.body).foregroundColor(.white).padding(5)
                            .background(Capsule())
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                            .padding(.top, -15)
                        Text(VFbalance.currency)
                            .bold().font(.system(.title3, design: .rounded))
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                        Text(VBbalance.currency)//entry.availableString)
                            .bold().font(.body).foregroundColor(.white).padding(5)
                            .background(Capsule())
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                            .padding(.top, -15)
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "chart.bar.fill")
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20).foregroundColor(.white).padding(5)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).foregroundColor(Color("AccentColor"))).frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    Text("Balance")
                        .bold()
                    Spacer()
                }
            }.padding()
        }
    }
    
    init(entry: Entry, context: NSPersistentContainer) {
        let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "mygroup")
        Fbalance = defaults?.value(forKey: "Fbalance") as! Double
        Bbalance = defaults?.value(forKey: "Bbalance") as! Double
        self.entry = entry
        var balance = 0.0

        context.performBackgroundTask { context in
            context.perform {
                let request = Transaction.request
                request.fetchLimit = 100
                let results = try! context.fetch(request)
                balance = results.filter { !$0.isPending }.map(\.amount).reduce(0, +)
                
            }
        }
        VBbalance = balance
        let results = try! context.viewContext.fetch(Transaction.request)
        VFbalance = results.filter { !$0.isPending }.map(\.amount).reduce(0, +)
    }
}

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {    
    let moc: NSPersistentContainer

    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> Entry {
        Entry()
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Entry) -> ()) {
        completion(Entry())
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        let entry = Entry()
        let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "mygroup")
        
        moc.performBackgroundTask { context in
            context.perform {
                let request = Transaction.request
                request.fetchLimit = 100
                let results = try! context.fetch(request)
                let balance = results.filter { !$0.isPending }.map(\.amount).reduce(0, +)
                defaults?.set(balance, forKey: "Bbalance")
            }
        }
        let results = try! moc.viewContext.fetch(Transaction.request)
        let balance = results.filter { !$0.isPending }.map(\.amount).reduce(0, +)
        defaults?.set(balance, forKey: "Fbalance")
        defaults?.synchronize()
        completion(Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .never))
    }
}

struct Entry: TimelineEntry {
let date: Date

init() {
    date = Date()
}

init(_ context: NSPersistentContainer) {
    date = Date()

    let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "mygroup")
    
    context.performBackgroundTask { context in
        context.perform {
            let request = Transaction.request
            let results = try! context.fetch(request)
            let balance = results.filter { !$0.isPending }.map(\.amount).reduce(0, +)
            defaults?.set(balance, forKey: "Bbalance")
        }
    }
    let results = try! context.viewContext.fetch(Transaction.request)
    let balance = results.filter { !$0.isPending }.map(\.amount).reduce(0, +)
    defaults?.set(balance, forKey: "Fbalance")
    defaults?.synchronize()
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Code added with all solutions that i have tried